# How to iterate through nested JSON with unique IDs?

Tags: python, json, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I'm working with a JSON object that lists every entry as a nested JSON object within DynamoDB. Each entry has a unique id generated as the JSON identifier. I'm trying to loop through each nested JSON entry entry and grab all of the values associated with that entry (ex."entry.34d6fd1269dd450cbe2437b942d68513.employeeLevel). Not sure how to for loop through each nested JSON entry without knowing the entry id. How would you go about this? The JSON object structure is listed below:

```
{
     "username": "test",
     "entry": {
      "34d6fd1269dd450cbe2437b942d68513": {
       "employeeLevel": "level one",
       "body": "Test 1",
       "cloudPlatformAoi": [
        "IBM Cloud or Watson"
       ],
       "cloudPlatformStrength": [
        "AWS"
       ],
       "databaseStrength": [
        "DynamoDB"
       ],
       "dbAoi": [
        "MySQL",
        "OpenSearch"
       ],
       "integratedDevelopmentEnvironment": [
        "PyCharm",
        "Sublime Text"
       ],
       "integratedDevelopmentEnvironmentAoi": [
        "PyCharm",
        "Sublime Text"
       ],
       "lastEdited": "09-Jun-2022 (13:31:13.095137)",
       "programmingLanguageAoi": [
        "CDK"
       ],
       "programmingLanguageStrength": [
        "CDK",
        "Java",
        "Python",
        "TypeScript"
       ],
       "timeCreated": "09-Jun-2022 (13:30:29.967379)",
       "title": "This is my first post (Edited)",
       "webFrameworkAoi": [
        "Laravel",
        "Ruby on Rails"
       ],
       "webFrameworkStrength": [
        "Flask"
       ]
      },
      "34dc811470ee459ab06ec70a1010b6b4": {
       "employeeLevel": "level two",
       "body": "Hello World 2!",
       "cloudPlatformAoi": [
        "Heroku"
       ],
       "cloudPlatformStrength": [
        "AWS"
       ],
       "databaseStrength": [
        "Couchbase"
       ],
       "dbAoi": [
        "Oracle"
       ],
       "integratedDevelopmentEnvironment": [
        "Vim"
       ],
       "integratedDevelopmentEnvironmentAoi": [
        "Vim"
       ],
       "lastEdited": "09-Jun-2022 (14:30:28.864071)",
       "programmingLanguageAoi": [
        "Elixir"
       ],
       "programmingLanguageStrength": [
        "Assembly"
       ],
       "timeCreated": "09-Jun-2022 (13:30:29.967379)",
       "title": "2 (edited)",
       "webFrameworkAoi": [
        "Spring"
       ],
       "webFrameworkStrength": [
        "jQuery"
       ]
      }
     },
     "useremail": "test@gmail.com"
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can capture the dictionary under `entry` by `d['entry']` (after loading the json into `d`), then iterate over each key under `entry` (assuming the keys under `entry` are the entry ids) and capture the dictionary for each entry id by `entry[id]`

```py
d = json.loads(s)
entry = d['entry']
for id in entry:
    do_something(entry[id])
```

Comment: You don't need to call `keys()`; the iterator for `dict` itself produces the keys of the `dict`.

Comment: You're right. Edited the answer.